# How can I figure out which version of apache POI is needed for jXLS 2.3.0?

Tags: apache-poi, jxls

This is my Gradle file:

```
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.13'
compile 'org.jxls:jxls-jexcel:1.0.6'
compile 'org.jxls:jxls-poi:1.0.9'
compile 'org.jxls:jxls:2.3.0'
```

It looks like I'm using the wrong version of apache POI:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.getCellStyleAt(S)Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle;
at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.clearCell(PoiTransformer.java:224)
at org.jxls.area.XlsArea.clearCells(XlsArea.java:437)
at org.jxls.builder.xls.XlsCommentAreaBuilder.build(XlsCommentAreaBuilder.java:181)
at org.jxls.template.SimpleExporter.gridExport(SimpleExporter.java:54)
```

Isn't it a bit strange that I have to explicitly include a dependency that another dependency depends upon? Moreover, how can I figure out which version of the dependency (the POI) I actually need?

I am just trying to get the simple exporter sample to work:

```
   try (InputStream is = CalXlsExporter.class.getResourceAsStream(template)) {
        try (OutputStream os2 = new FileOutputStream("ExportOutput.xlsx")) {

            headers = Arrays.asList(HEADERS);

            Context context = new Context();
            context.putVar("headers", HEADERS);
            context.putVar("cell", cal);

            JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os2, context); //Exception inside this
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always look at the Maven pom file of jxls-poi module for example you can see that [jxls-poi-1.0.9](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jxls/jxls-poi/1.0.9/jxls-poi-1.0.9.pom) contains a dependency to POI 3.12 as defined in pom properties section

```
<properties>
  ...
  <poi.version>3.12</poi.version>
  ...  
</properties>
```

It may happen that later POI versions can also work but it is not always the case because it depends on Apache POI backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to simply remove the dependency on POI in your file as jxls will drag in the correct version of POI as transitive dependency anyway, so you just need to depend on jxls in your application always and future updates will not cause similar strange errors.